# How to get back to the Logic Editor?

Tags: interface, logic-bricks

So, I accidentally hit some key, I don't know what, and it took me out of the Game Logic screen. Now I can't get back to it.

[image: blender]

Any ideas? Otherwise I will have to start over a long process.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the Properties being on the right side instead of the left, at the bottom left of the screen, you can select the logic editor. This is what I've been using since I didn't know there even was a Game Logic choice.
[image: Pic showing Logic Editor]